# While loop causing problem with variables in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am doing ['The Longest Possible Prefix'](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/) problem on LeetCode and to solve it I have implemented the code:

```
strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
s = ['']
b = []
a = 1
while s.count(s[0])==len(s) and s[0] != strs[0]:
    b = s
    s.clear()
    for i in strs:
        s.append(i[0:a])
    a+=1
print(b[0])
```

I have used an extra variable `b` to keep a previous version of the list `s` before I update it. The problem is that even when the while loop has broken `b` has again been set to the value of `s` giving a value that I don not want. Why is this happening and how could I fix it?

Comment: Your problem is with references versus values.  Lists pass by reference so your `b` is effectively _the same piece of memory_ as `s`

Comment: You need `b = s.copy()`